# How can execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active in yii?

Tags: sql, yii

I have some sql command in controller yii

my query command is true but when i want to execute it i have **CDbException**.
I left my code here i don't how can solve it.
 I thinks when I execute some query command I get error because when I execute a query command i have not any problem.

```
$queryb = "DROP TABLE if exists poli;";
        $queryb .= "CREATE VIEW poli AS
                SELECT `user_Id` , count( `psh_profile_information_services`.id ) as internetcount
    FROM `psh_profile_information`
    INNER JOIN `psh_profile_information_services` ON `psh_profile_information`.`id` = `psh_profile_information_services`.`profileInformationId`
    WHERE `serviceId` =1
    GROUP BY `psh_profile_information`.`user_Id` ";

       $command= $connection->createCommand($queryb);
       $command->execute(); 

        $sql = "SELECT  `profile`.`scope_id` , SUM( internetcount ) 
FROM  `psh_profiles` AS profile
INNER JOIN  `poli` ON  `profile`.`user_id` =  `poli`.`user_Id` 
GROUP BY  `profile`.`scope_id` ";

        $internetcountOfRows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

this code can  create "view pori", but can not do "$sql" query.

**CDbException**:

```
General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.
Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().
Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql,
you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `profile`.`scope_id` , SUM( internetcount )
FROM `psh_profiles` AS profile
INNER JOIN `poli` ON `profile`.`user_id` = `poli`.`user_Id`
GROUP BY `profile`.`scope_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this before execute:

```
$command->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);
```

Comment: i write your command before $command->execute(); 
i have error: CDbCommand and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "setAttribute".

Comment: try: `Yii::app()->db->->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);`